# Google Chrome swf issue with allow button

Tags: flash, google-chrome

Please take a look at the image am attaching, as you can note its not readable nor it is clickable am only facing this issue in google chrome an idea why is that happening ?!!

- Google Chrome    14.0.835.186 (Official Build 101821) m
- OS   Windows
- WebKit   535.1 (branches/chromium/835@94713)
- JavaScript   V8 3.4.14.21
- Flash    10,3,183,10

Thanks

[image]

Comment: flash player and chrome versions will be helpful addition to your post

Comment: I'd also suggest simply filing a bug against Chromium: http://new.crbug.com/ will be more effective at diagnosing potential flash interaction problems than StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will digging into this i found the solution of my question.

The container of the flash object did have a style of "**border-radius**" removing this solved the issue.